# Why tcp server receives one buffer if Client sends multiple buffer without sleep?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

My Client is sending to the server correctly if I send buffers after some interval. But if I send messages without interval server receives one buffer.For example if i send two buffers "message1" and "message2" and puts 1 second sleep between this two sending operation server receives 2 buffers and prints message1 "\n" message2. But if I send these 2 buffers without sleep server gets 1 buffer and prints message1message2. I can't understand why it is happening.My server and client code are as follows.

server.c

```
            #include<stdio.h>
            #include<string.h>    //strlen
            #include<stdlib.h>    //strlen
            #include<sys/socket.h>
            #include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
            #include<unistd.h>    //write

            #include<pthread.h> //for threading , link with lpthread

            void *connection_handler(void *);

            int main(int argc, char *argv[])
            {
                int socket_desc, new_socket, c, *new_sock;
                struct sockaddr_in server, client;
                char *message;

                //Create socket
                socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
                if (socket_desc == -1)
                {
                    printf("Could not create socket");
                }

                //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
                server.sin_family = AF_INET;
                server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
                server.sin_port = htons(10240);

                //Bind
                if (bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
                {
                    puts("bind failed");
                    return 1;
                }
                puts("bind done");

                //Listen
                listen(socket_desc, 3);

                //Accept and incoming connection
                puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
                c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
                while ((new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)))
                {
                    puts("Connection accepted");

                    //Reply to the client
            //      message = "Hello Client , I have received your connection. And now I will assign a handler for you\n";
            //      write(new_socket, message, strlen(message));

                    pthread_t sniffer_thread;
                    new_sock = malloc(1);
                    *new_sock = new_socket;

                    if (pthread_create(&sniffer_thread, NULL, connection_handler, (void*)new_sock) < 0)
                    {
                        perror("could not create thread");
                        return 1;
                    }

                    //Now join the thread , so that we dont terminate before the thread
                    //pthread_join( sniffer_thread , NULL);
                    puts("Handler assigned");
                }

                if (new_socket<0)
                {
                    perror("accept failed");
                    return 1;
                }
                while (1);
                return 0;
            }



            void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
            {
                //Get the socket descriptor
                int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
                int read_size;
                char *message, client_message[2000];

                //Send some messages to the client
            //  message = "Greetings! I am your connection handler\n";
            //  write(sock, message, strlen(message));
            // 
            //  message = "Now type something and i shall repeat what you type \n";
            //  write(sock, message, strlen(message));

                //Receive a message from client
                while ((read_size = recv(sock, client_message, 2000, 0)) > 0)
                {
                    puts(client_message);
                    //Send the message back to client
                    //write(sock, client_message, strlen(client_message));
                    memset(client_message, 0, sizeof(client_message));
                }

                if (read_size == 0)
                {
                    puts("Client disconnected");
                    fflush(stdout);
                }
                else if (read_size == -1)
                {
                    perror("recv failed");
                }

                //Free the socket pointer
                free(socket_desc);

                return 0;
            }
```

client.c

```
            #include<stdio.h>
            #include<string.h>    //strlen
            #include<sys/socket.h>
            #include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr

            int main(int argc, char *argv[])
            {
                int socket_desc;
                struct sockaddr_in server;
                char *message, server_reply[2000];

                //Create socket
                socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
                if (socket_desc == -1)
                {
                    printf("Could not create socket");
                }

                server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.246.26");
                server.sin_family = AF_INET;
                server.sin_port = htons(10240);

                //Connect to remote server
                if (connect(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
                {
                    puts("connect error");
                    return 1;
                }

                puts("Connected\n");

                //Send some data
                message = "nayan";
                if (send(socket_desc, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0)
                {
                    puts("Send failed");
                    return 1;
                }
                /*sleep(1);*/
                message = NULL;
                message = "Mazhar vai";

                if (send(socket_desc, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0)
                {
                    puts("Send failed");
                    return 1;
                }
                /*sleep(1);*/
                message = NULL;
                message = "Sarwar vai";

                if (send(socket_desc, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0)
                {
                    puts("Send failed");
                    return 1;
                }
                /*sleep(1);*/
                message = NULL;
                message = "joy";

                if (send(socket_desc, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0)
                {
                    puts("Send failed");
                    return 1;
                }
                /*sleep(1);*/
                message = NULL;
                message = "sumon";

                if (send(socket_desc, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0)
                {
                    puts("Send failed");
                    return 1;
                }
                /*sleep(1);*/
                message = NULL;
                message = "rahim";

                if (send(socket_desc, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0)
                {
                    puts("Send failed");
                    return 1;
                }
                /*sleep(1);*/
                message = NULL;
                message = "karim";

                if (send(socket_desc, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0)
                {
                    puts("Send failed");
                    return 1;
                }

                /*sleep(1);*/
                message = NULL;
                message = "jamal";

                if (send(socket_desc, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0)
                {
                    puts("Send failed");
                    return 1;
                }
                /*sleep(1);*/
                message = NULL;
                message = "kamal";

                if (send(socket_desc, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0)
                {
                    puts("Send failed");
                    return 1;
                }
                /*sleep(1);*/ 
                message = NULL;
                message = "salam";

                if (send(socket_desc, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0)
                {
                    puts("Send failed");
                    return 1;
                }
                //Receive a reply from the server
            //  if (recv(socket_desc, server_reply, 2000, 0) < 0)
            //  {
            //      puts("recv failed");
            //  }
            //  puts("Reply received\n");
            //  puts(server_reply);

                return 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TCP is a *streaming* protocol (as indicated by the use of `SOCK_STREAM`). That means there are no packet beginnings or ends, it's all just a single stream of bytes. It also means that a single receive call may read less than was sent using a single transmit call, or what was sent with multiple (including a trailing partial) transmit calls.

To handle it you need to come up with a higher-level protocol to put on top of TCP. It either needs to contain the length of the data being sent (in a fixed-length format), or you need to have some other way to know the beginning or at least the end of a message.

Comment: Also, Send Coalescing via the Nagle Algorithm, which is enabled by default (see the `TCP_NODELAY` socket option), may be buffering sends that are close together so that they can be transmitted using fewer but more efficient network packets.

Comment: Is it also true for sctp connection?

Comment: @Nayan [SCTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol) is a message-based protocol, similar to UDP in that respect.

Comment: Why tcp server is receiving buffer larger than maximum size of the buffer to read in one read in recv function in case sender sends data at high rate?  For example recv(sock, client_message, 2000, 0). Sometimes I get received message larger than 2000.

Comment: @Nayan That's not possible. If you call `recv` with a size of `2000`, it will return between `-1` and `2000` (inclusive). How do you check what you receive?

Comment: I set the max size 1500 not 2000 in the recv function. What ever I received I wrote that text to a file. It receives less than 1500 in one read most of the time but sometimes it reads more than 1500. I check it by counting characters in notepad++. The exceptional scenario occurs only when the sender sends at a higher rate. But when I have increased the max size 1500 to 6400 the exceptional scenario never happened because it never reads more than 6400. But I am confused why these are happening.

Comment: @Nayan Then I would say that your *writing* to the file is wrong. Do the other end send a null-terminated string? If not, then you can't treat it as such in your program. If you want the data you receive to be a null-terminated string you need to explicitly terminate it. For example doing something like `int ret = recv(..., data, ...); if (ret > 0) { data[ret] = '\0'; }`

Comment: @Nayan Checking your code again, that's definitely the problem you have now: Strings that are not terminated. The client when it sends string doesn't include the terminator in what it send. The server needs to explicitly add it (as shown in my previous comment).